# SML - if's condition with some "or"

Tags: sml

I want to make a if condition like this:

```
if

 ((head(c) = 1) or (head(c) = ~1) or (head(c) = ~5) or (head(c) = ~17) or (head(c) = 0))
count +1
else..
```

the function head return 'a;

It gives me the next error: `operator is not a function [tycon dismatch]`
operator: bool
in expression

What is the problem? thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it's called `orelse` in SML.

Answer (score 5):

It's called `orelse`, not just `or` and `andalso` instead of `and`. But `orelse` and `andalso` are not functions. Citation from *Programming in Standard ML '97*:

> Note in particular that andalso and orelse are not infix functions because they are not strict in their second argument—that is, they do not always force the evaluation of their second argument—and such functions cannot be defined in a strict programming language such as Standard ML. Thus we cannot apply the op keyword to andalso or orelse.

Answer (score 1):

For this example, you could also write:

```
let val h = head c in
if List.exists (fn x => x = h) [1, ~1, ~5, ~17, 0]
then count + 1
else ...
end
```